# Obj-C: Convert an Array of objects into an NSDictionary for use with JSONRepresentation

Tags: objective-c, json, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary, sbjson

I have an NSMutableArray of custom objects with various information them.
For instance the object might contain:

```
firstname
lastname
email
```

I'd like to be able to add these objects to an NSDictionary, so that I can call SBJSON's 'JSONRepresentation' Function, and the final JSON format would look like:

```
{
    "Users" : [
               { "user1First" : "FirstName",
                 "user1Last"  : "LastName",
                 "user1Email" : "Email" },
               { "user2First" : "FirstName",
                 "user2Last"  : "LastName",
                 "user2Email" : "Email" },
               { "user3First" : "FirstName",
                 "user3Last"  : "LastName",
                 "user3Email" : "Email" }
               ]
}
```

Comment: I think you should clarify this question a bit more.  Are you trying to generate a number of users with the same values as "FirstName" etc?  I don't understand well enough to help.

Comment: "FirstName", "LastName" and "Email" are the keys for the JSON Values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a `dictionaryRepresentation` for each of your custom classes that returns a dictionary for that particular object. Then you can do something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *dictionaryArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:yourOtherArray.count];
for (id object in yourOtherArray) {
    [dictionaryArray addObject:[object dictionaryRepresentation]];
}
// not sure what SBJSON's function returns so I'm using id here
id JSONRepresentation = [dictionaryArray JSONRepresentation];
```

Comment: Instead of `NSObject *object`, I would use `id object`. That will prevent a warning.

Comment: Good idea. Edited to reflect.

Comment: `dictionaryRepresentation` iOS6 and above